# Use a function both directly and as a lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

Is there a better way to implement this? Should I be concerned about the performance of the Compile method here?

```
     Public Overrides Function GetValidSerialNumbers() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of SerialNumber)
        Return Queryable.Where(allSerials, SerialNumberValidFunc)
     End Function

     Public Overrides Function IsSerialNumberValid(serialNumber As SerialNumber) As Boolean
        Return (SerialNumberValidFunc.Compile().Invoke(serialNumber))
     End Function

     Private ReadOnly Property SerialNumberValidFunc As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of SerialNumber, Boolean))
        Get
           If ProductionReceiptLine.MOOutput Is Nothing Then
              Return Function(sn As SerialNumber) sn.ItemInventory Is Nothing AndAlso _
                    (sn.Status = SerialNumberStatusValues.Planned AndAlso sn.MO Is ProductionReceiptLine.ProductionReceipt.MO _
                     OrElse sn.Status = SerialNumberStatusValues.Assigned)
           Else
              Return Function(sn As SerialNumber) sn.ItemInventory Is Nothing AndAlso _
                    (sn.Status = SerialNumberStatusValues.Planned AndAlso sn.MO Is Nothing OrElse sn.Status = SerialNumberStatusValues.Assigned)
           End If
        End Get
     End Property
```

The reason I want the lambda expression is because I want that function to be able to get all the way through LINQ-to-SQL to be converted to SQL. The reason I want the direct version is because I have other code that I want to validate individual serial numbers before submitting changes. And I fear that `GetValidSerialNumbers.Contains(serialNumber)` will execute a more-complex-than-necesssary query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Compile method is very slow because it needs to emit IL from your expression. Invoking the compiled function will cause another compile: the JIT compilation.

I suggest you cache the result of Compile in a static field or so.

The general approach you are taking is good. It is DRY.

Comment: The problem with caching is that in this form, the cached function would only serve callers for an individual ProductionReceiptLine. However, the code could probably be rewritten to cache a version of the function that accepts ProductionReceiptLine as a parameter instead of having it hardwired into the Lambda expression. In the end, I decided to be less DRY because there were some other differences between the cases. So I simply duplicated the code. But it's good to know that Compile is as expensive as it sounds.

Comment: Now that I think about it, ProdutionLine and Me (aka this) would be implicit parameters to the function (closure?) would they not? Could one copy of the function be pre-compiled on a shared (aka static) class member and serve all instances? I haven't quite thought it through, but there might be something there.